# How to run my scrip python openCV on docker, Ubuntu

Tags: python, docker, opencv, ubuntu, terminal

I am using docker for the first time. I am using this image **opencvcourses/opencv-docker**.
I try to run a scrip with openCV, but first i am going to explain how i run a simple code with print and numpy

I have my script (ej.py) on my ubuntu local directory: /home/noemi/Escritorio/contenedores/cont1/ej.py

```
import numpy as np
print('Esto es una prueba ok')
print(np.pi)
```

I run docker with the next command

```
docker run -it -v /home/noemi/Escritorio/contenedores/cont1:/home opencvcourses/opencv-docker
```

And, my script works! I obtain this

```
Esto es una prueba ok
3.141592653589793
```

But when I add to my script (ej.py) openCV code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = np.zeros((6,8,1),np.uint8)

cv2.imshow('imagen-zeros',img1)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and try with the same command

```
docker run -it -v /home/noemi/Escritorio/contenedores/cont1:/home opencvcourses/opencv-docker
```

appear this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ej.py", line 6, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('imagen-zeros',img1)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) /home/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window_gtk.cpp:624: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Can't initialize GTK backend in function 'cvInitSystem'
```

Please, I don't know what happened

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution reading this post https://www.programmersought.com/article/15656181875/

I have a script named **ej.py** on my ubuntu location **/home/noemi/Escritorio/contenedores/cont1**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

print('Esto es una prueba ok')
print(np.pi)
img = cv2.imread('gato.jpg')

cv2.imshow('imagen-zeros',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

To run my code using docker image **opencvcourses/opencv-docker** follow the next steps, its works for me:

```
$ xhost +local:docker
$ docker run -it --device /dev/video0:/dev/video0 -v $(pwd):/home -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -p 5000:5000 -p 8888:8888 opencvcourses/opencv-docker
```

the previous command create a container and open the image bash. Here write python3 ej.py like this:

```
root@ee4316d99815:/home# python3 ej.py
```

and it works! My code show the image

If you want execute the container again try with this:

1. Identify the ID of container with:
   $ docker ps -a
2. Start the container with:
   $ docker start (ID container like this ee4316d99815)
3. Execute the container with:
   $ docker exec -it ee4316d99815 /bin/bash
4. And try again with python3 ej.py

Maybe if you want close xhost, you should use $ xhost -local:docker

Answer (score 0):

### docker run command

```
docker run -it -v /home/noemi/Escritorio/contenedores/cont1:/home opencvcourses/opencv-docker
```

### Explanation

1. Sets DISPLAY environment variable value to be the same as HOST's.

`--env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY`

2. Helps in X11 forwarding so that we can use functions like `cv::imshow`

`-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix`

And let me know if this works to update this answer accordingly.

### Sources

- [Install OpenCV Docker Image on Ubuntu, MacOS or Windows](https://learnopencv.com/install-opencv-docker-image-ubuntu-macos-windows/)
- [No address associated with hostname](https://forums.balena.io/t/startx-hostname-no-address-associated-with-hostname/188858)
- [error: (-2:Unspecified error) Can't initialize GTK backend in function 'cvInitSystem'](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/18461)

Comment: Hi om-ha, I prove the three commands and not work for me, I obtain the same error... Maybe you know other solution that I can use... thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Updated my answer, try it out and let me know.

Comment: Waiting for your input @Noemí

Comment: Sorry, no work for me :( I try this: $ docker run -it --device /dev/video0:/dev/video0 -v $(pwd):/home -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -p 5000:5000 -p 8888:8888 opencvcourses/opencv-docker  ...my code prints (np.pi), but not cv2.imshow. I obtain the same error: 
No protocol specified
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ej.py", line 8, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('imagen-zeros',img1)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) /home/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window_gtk.cpp:624: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Can't initialize GTK backend in function 'cvInitSystem'

Comment: Dear om-ha! I read this post https://www.programmersought.com/article/15656181875/ and I try with: $ xhost +local:docker and later with: docker run -it --device /dev/video0:/dev/video0 -v $(pwd):/home -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -p 5000:5000 -p 8888:8888 opencvcourses/opencv-docker  ...and my code WORKS! thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad it worked, you're most welcome! How about turning what worked for you into an answer?

Comment: It's ok. i am going to write my anwser